# Which values of n allow for n-tuples of consecutive natural numbers that sum to a square?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

So if we take examples, we can see that any odd number $(2n+1)^2= (n+1)+(n+2)+\ldots+(3n+1)$. This is backwards though, because I'm trying to find out which (if not all) lengths of consecutive integers (e.g pairs, triplets etc) can have a square sum. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As $k+(k+1)+\ldots + (k+n)=\frac{(n+k)(n+k+1)}2-\frac{k(k-1)}2$, you want to find $n$ such that $$(n+k)(n+k+1)-k(k-1)=2m^2 $$
has solutions. This simplifies to
$$(n+1)(n+2k)=2m^2.$$
Write $n+1=2^ru$ with $r\ge 0$ and $u$ odd.
Then we ask for the solvability of 
$$2^ru(2^ru+2k-1)=2m^2.$$

- If $r$ is even and $>0$, this is impossible.
- If $r=0$ (i.e., $n$ is even), we can let $m=n+1$ and $k=\frac n2+1$.
- If $r$ is odd, $r=2s+1$, we can let $m=2^sut$, where $t$ is odd and  big enough, and then let $k=\frac{u(t^2-2^r)+1}2$.

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution. Would you mind going through the motivation for your steps with me in a bit of detail? 

1. How would you demonstrate that it is unsolvable for even r?

2. I don't really understand the point in discussion odd values of r, because surely they're a subset the values for r=0?

3.Also, the substitution of n+1 = (2^r)*u; Is it a generally useful technique or is it specific to the question?